# Cannot find module '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts

Tags: ethers.js, uniswapv3

according to uniswap v3 docs we should install these modules:

npm i --save-dev @uniswap/v3-sdk
npm i --save-dev @uniswap/sdk-core

then for the quoter abi:
@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol/Quoter.json

but there is no directory for @uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts

so always get an error

Error: Cannot find module '@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol/Quoter.json'

Answer (score 1):

the recent version (1.4.2) has a problem I think. the package does not contain the artifacts folder.
I installed a previous version and it worked.

```
$ yarn add -D @uniswap/v3-periphery@1.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved it by cd into the `node_modules/@uniswap/v3-periphery`, run `npm i` followed by `npx hardhat compile`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed @uniswap/v3-periphery?

```
npm i --save-dev @uniswap/v3-periphery
```

afterward, just import it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`yarn add -D @uniswap/v3-periphery@1.4.1`

This worked for me, but since I don't have enough reputation, I can't comment or upvote. Original answer can be found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/136431/110186) consider upvoting it if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I have this version installed:

```
      "@uniswap/v3-periphery": "^1.4.3",
```

and it works

```
import UniswapV3Quote from "@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol/Quoter.json";
console.log({ UniswapV3Quote });
```